# How to delete boto3 DynamoDB key?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

This is my DynamoDB JSON

```
{
  "follow_count": 3,
  "followed_back_count": 4,
  "followed_back_users": [
    32432
  ],
  "login": "login1",
  "target": "target1",
  "target_followed_users": [
    234232342,
    453453434,
    241413422
  ]
}
```

I need to delete the `target_followed_users` from the db so I tired this...

```
# Update for followed_back_users
table.update_item(
    Key={
        'login': login,
        'target': target,
    },
    UpdateExpression='DELETE followed_back_users = :followed_back_users',
    ExpressionAttributeValues={
        ':followed_back_users': db_followed_back_users
    }
)
```

I got below error..

> botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the UpdateItem operation: Invalid UpdateExpression: Syntax error; token: "=", near: "followed_back_users = :followed_back_users"

Answer (score 1):

That's definitely not [the correct syntax](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.UpdateExpressions.html#Expressions.UpdateExpressions.DELETE). If you want to delete a specific item from your `target_followed_users` set then you would use the syntax:

`UpdateExpression='DELETE followed_back_users :followed_back_users'`

where `followed_back_user` would be the list of values to delete from the set.

If you want to to completely remove the `followed_back_users` attribute from the DynamoDB record, then you would use the following syntax:

`UpdateExpression='REMOVE followed_back_users'`

Comment: db_followed_back_users is a list. I will try with `REMOVE` you have mention may be this is what I want I think. Let me check and come back to you. Thanks for the answer though.